# Bottom text align or menu

Tags: css, menu, vertical-alignment

I have a menu the have rectangular boxes 90x50. Some have single line text, other have multiline text

question : How to VERTICALLY align it to the bottom with pure css no hack please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vertical aligninment in CSS isn't that easy as you'd intuitively expect. As far the straightforward property `vertical-align: bottom` works in table cells only. Here's an excellent resource which explains how (not) to vertical align in CSS: [Understanding vertical-align, or "How (Not) To Vertically Center Content"](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html).

In a nut: the following works in real webbrowsers:

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: bottom;
```

But thus not in MSIE. You'd like to make the parent element relative and wrap the text in an absolutely positioned element and then put it to bottom. Here's a copy'n'paste'n'runnable example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <style>
            li {
                position: relative;
                width: 90px; 
                height: 50px; 
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
            li span {
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li><span>text</span></li>
            <li><span>text<br>multiline</span></li>
            <li><span>text</span></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: very interesting... but i have found : http://www.trash-factor.com/content/vertical-align-text-inside-div-container-css that show a solution maybe better for a MENU vie a href... i let you know !

Answer (score 0):

I think the `vertical-align` property does what you want. Otherwise, perhaps you can clarify your problem further?

Edit: You can force table-cell-like behaviour for any other element by using the `display` property with the value 'table-cell'. I am not perfectly sure if this works with well with the `vertical-align` property, but perhaps you can build on it. If I remember correctly, an additional intermediate element was required.

Comment: I know, but it's apply to table cell... i like text in a div